# "Popular with" vs "Popular among"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, prepositions

> Prof. Sat is not popular with/among his students.

Which usage is correct here and why?

Comment: Intuitively, "not popular with" is referring to the students as a body with one opinion; "not popular among" means not many among the students like him.

Answer (score 5):

"Popular among" and "popular with" are both correct. In this case, I would suggest "popular with".

"Popular with" is usually used for people, e.g. "Popular with the girls", "Popular with the working class..."

"Popular among" is usually used with ideas among people, eg. "The new policy is not going to popular among the members of the party...."

Comment: I don't know that I buy into the "people vs ideas" distinction.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "*popular with*" just generally seems to be more popular with people regardless whether it's the popularity of people or things.

Compare the ngram for "***it*** is popular *among*" vs "***it*** is popular *with*":

[image]

To that of "***he*** is popular *among*" vs "***he*** is popular *with*":

[image]

Comment: These Ngrams sure are **popular among** this community...

Comment: Yes they do seem to be.  I would also note that they are quite popular with this community.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Corpus enTenTen18, both "popular with"  and "popular among" are grammatically correct and the former is more frequently used.      [image][image][image]

Comment: But do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

According to longman, "popular with" is right. 
He is popular with friends.

Comment: But does this prove that 'popular among' is incorrect? Your answer has a reference, though, which Bidella's fails to include.

Comment: It's a rule, and the rules are to rule. You are free to write whatever you yearn to write.

Comment: (a) What, are you claiming, is a rule here?  I could say "According to [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/among), which gives 'a custom popular among the Greeks', 'popular among' is right. It's a rule."  But that would give the impression that 'popular with' probably 'isn't right'. (b) Notice that I gave a link to the actual page containing the quote.